# Прблема с django-db-mailer

Tags: django, redis

Пытаюсь установить django-db-mailer. Действую в точности по инструкции, но почему-то не могу сохранить шаблон письма. Пробовал и через консоль, и с морды, вылетает ошибка:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.114.121:1234/admin/dbmail/mailtemplate/add/

Django Version: 2.0.13
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['grappelli.dashboard',
 'grappelli',
 'sslserver',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dbmail',
 'django_extensions',
 'reversion',
 'reversion_compare',
 'djcelery',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reversion/admin.py" in add_view
  170.             return super(VersionAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1554.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1491.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1027.         obj.save()

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/src/django-db-mailer/dbmail/models.py" in save
  273.         self._clean_cache()

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/src/django-db-mailer/dbmail/models.py" in _clean_cache
  228.         cache.delete(self.slug, version=1)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py" in _decorator
  34.             return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py" in delete
  93.         return self.client.delete(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py" in delete
  248.             client = self.get_client(write=True)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py" in get_client
  94.             self._clients[index] = self.connect(index)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py" in connect
  107.         return self.connection_factory.connect(self._server[index])

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py" in connect
  71.         connection = self.get_connection(params)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py" in get_connection
  82.         pool = self.get_or_create_connection_pool(params)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py" in get_or_create_connection_pool
  101.             self._pools[key] = self.get_connection_pool(params)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py" in get_connection_pool
  114.         pool = self.pool_cls.from_url(**cp_params)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/db-mailer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py" in from_url
  997.                              'schemes (%s)' % valid_schemes)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/dbmail/mailtemplate/add/
Exception Value: Redis URL must specify one of the followingschemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Хотя бы подскажите, где искать косячный URL

Comment: Можно ещё меньше кода? Тогда точно Вам помогут.

Comment: https://django-db-mailer.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, собственно оттуда я демку запустить и пытался. Кода и не успел написать никакого. Вот та инструкция, которой я следовал:
https://django-db-mailer.readthedocs.io/demo.html

Comment: Redis у Вас запущен?

Comment: @RomualdShmidtelson, запущен, но я его никак не настраивал